# Generic functions in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am not very familiar with some of the generic syntax in Java.
I came across some code like this:

```
public static<T> T foo(T... a)
```

Can somebody explain what it means in a succinct way?
Does it mean foo() takes in an array of type T and returns type T?
Why isn't the syntax like this below?

```
public static T foo(T[] a)
```

I had a look at the Oracle docs but the example they have seems much easier to understand: [Oracle Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: *"Why isn't the syntax like this below?"* All types have a declaration! `<T>` is a declaration of a type parameter. Everything has a declaration. ; )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1) This is a varargs method, a method that takes a variable number of arguments. That is not the same as a method that takes an array (even though under the hoods it is implemented using an array).

You call this method as `foo(a,b,c)` (as opposed to `foo(arrayWithABC)`).

2) If you want to use the generic type placeholder `T`, you have to declare it. This is exactly what the first `<T>` does.

The difference between `public static T foo(T a)` and `public static <T> T foo(T a)` is that the latter introduced a "local" `T` for the scope of this method. That means "method returns an instance of *whatever type* parameter `a` has". In the first version, the `T` would need to be a type placeholder declared elsewhere (such as on the class as a whole), or a class name.

Since `<T>` is completely unrestricted you can pass anything. What the generics do is bind the return value to the same type. If you just had `public static Object foo(Object a)`, you could pass in an `Integer` and get back a `String`. The `T` prevents that.

If you wanted to restrict the acceptable types, you could do `public static <T extends Number> T foo(T a)`.

Comment: ok, so in the latter case you mention (public static <T> T foo (T a)), it would be legal to call foo(String) or foo(BigInteger) but in the former case (public static T foo(T a)) one is restricted in what values T can take. Is this a correct way of looking at it?

Comment: Yes. Since `<T>` is completely unrestricted you can pass anything. What the generics do is bind the return value to the same type.

Comment: in the case where it was (T... a), can I pass objects which have a common ancestor? Eg (Circle, Square, Rhombus) where say these inherit from a superclass called Shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
T... a
```

means variable number of T type objects arguments for the method whereas

```
T[] a
```

means a single argument of array of T objects

Comment: Ok, yes I just realized that as soon as I hit send but what about the <T> before the return type, what is the purpose and significance of that?

Comment: The <T> is just defining the class T as it will be used later.

That seems a bit silly in the case above but is more useful in something like:


    public static<T extends Number> T foo(T... a)

Comment: @GregoryGraham: Not silly at all. It forces the return value to be of the same type as the input value.

Answer (score 0):

This means the type 'T' will match to any real type. Its like a wild-card type :)